# Visualization of chain rule for multivariable functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What is the difference between the derivative of two-variable function (which describe a surface in $Oxyz$ coordinate system): $z(t)=f(x(t),y(t)) \to \frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}\frac{dy}{dt}$

and the derivative of position vector $\vec{r}(t)=\langle x(t),y(t),z(t) \rangle \to \vec{r'}(t)=\langle\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dy}{dt},\frac{dz}{dt}\rangle$

As far as I know, $\vec{r'}(t)$ can be interpreted as the tangent line of the surface. However, I still can't get rid of the thought that the derivative of a function $z'(t)$ describe it's tangent line. I know that those two are different from each other but can't find a way to imagine what $r'(t)$ looks like geometrically, will it describe tangent lines in $Ozt$ coordinate system? If not then what does it look like in $Oxyz$ coordinate system?

Answer (score 1):

One important difference between the derivative of a two variable function vs the derivative of a position vector is the output of the functions. In the first case, the output is a scalar, in the second, a vector. So the domain and range are different.

These expressions are closely related, though. For real scalar function $f$ and typical assumptions about the relevant derivatives, $df=\nabla f\cdot \vec{ds} $ where $\nabla f$ is the gradient of $f$ and $\vec{ds}$ is an infinitesimal change in position as a vector.

Geometrically $\vec{r'(t)}$ is a vector tangent to the curve swept out by the position vector. It representes the velocity of the particle whose trajectory is given by $\vec{r(t)}$.

$\nabla f$ is perpendicular to the curve $f(x,y,z)=$constant, for if $\vec{ds}$ is tangent to the surface and $df=0$ then $\nabla f$ is perpendicular to that tangent.